# Cannot compile glosses using gb4e package

Tags: gb4e

I'm trying to add glosses to my paper using TexMaker, MikTex and the gb4e package. But every time I hit compile it takes forever until it finally spits out an error (basically saying that it took too long to compile and therefore has been aborted).
Everything worked fine before using the gb4e-package. When I mark the lines starting with \gll and \glt as comments no problems occur. It looks like this.

```
        \documentclass{report}
        \usepackage{setspace}
        \usepackage{hyphenat}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage[round]{natbib}
        \usepackage[hyphens]{url}
        \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
        \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
        \frenchspacing
        \Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu
        \usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

    \begin{exe}
    \ex
    \begin{xlist}
        \ex
        \gll Die Opposition wird mehr Strenge gegen\"uber auff\"allig gewordenen Ausl\"andern fordern\footnote{sueddeutsche.de, 20/02/2015} \\
        The opposition will more strictness {in the face of} conspicuous been foreigners demand \\
        \glt \enquote{The opposition will demand more strictness in the face of conspicuous foreigners.}
    \end{xlist}
    \end{exe}

\bibliography{tfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Doesn't my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

This is because you can not use `\footnote`s there. Use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` instead, if you want a footnote.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\frenchspacing
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill % just to fill the page, remove it

    \begin{exe}
    \ex
    \begin{xlist}
        \ex
        \gll Die Opposition wird mehr Strenge gegen\"uber auff\"allig gewordenen Ausl\"andern fordern\footnotemark \\
        The opposition will more strictness {in the face of} conspicuous been foreigners demand \\
        \glt \enquote{The opposition will demand more strictness in the face of conspicuous foreigners.}
    \end{xlist}
    \footnotetext{sueddeutsche.de, 20/02/2015}
    \end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]